# Electron not found when splitting main.ts in different files

Tags: typescript, electron

I'm getting this error while trying to split a working main.ts into more files.
Any idea on how to achieve it?

```
Uncaught Exception:

Error: Cannot find module 'xxx/app/node_modules/electron'
Require stack:
   - /xxx/app/windows/main2.js
   - /xxx/app/main.js
```

On my electron 13 project `main.ts` I have this:

```
import { app } from "electron";
import { createWindow, mainWindow } from "./windows/main";

app.on("ready", () => setTimeout(createWindow, 400));
```

while `windows/main.ts` is:

```
import { BrowserWindow, screen } from "electron";
import * as path from "path";
import * as url from "url";
import * as fs from "fs";
const args = process.argv.slice(1);
let serve: boolean; // true: node (angular), false: browser(angularJS)
serve = args.some((val) => val === "--serve");
export let mainWindow: BrowserWindow;

export function createWindow(): BrowserWindow {
  const electronScreen = screen;
  const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: serve ? true : false,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  if (serve) {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    require("electron-reload")(__dirname, {
      electron: require(path.join(__dirname, "/../node_modules/electron")),
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:4200");
  } else {
    // Path when running electron executable
    let pathIndex = "./index.html";

    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"))) {
      // Path when running electron in local folder
      pathIndex = "../dist/index.html";
    }

    mainWindow.loadURL(
      url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, pathIndex),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true,
      })
    );
  }

  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  return mainWindow;
}
```

Comment: please run a code formatter like [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) before posting code online. I have edited your post and done that for you.

Comment: I do, but when pasting here, it goes ugly. I will check why, thanks !